# PUP.HighConfidence While Building APK with Unity3D

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, apk, pup

I am using latest version of Unity in Mac. And the android apk built from it gave PUP.HighConfidence, virus flaged on virustotal.com.
I do not know the actual reason about this problem. I have faced similar problem on Windows 7 and Windows 10. Can anyone help me know why I am getting so and how can I get rid of it?

Thanks